# Beginner her. Could someone interpret this sentence. Thank you

Tags: python, list, loops

Suppose you are given a string and you want to count how many times each letter appears. There are several ways you could do it:

1. You could create 26 variables, one for each letter of the alphabet. Then you could traverse the string and, for each character, increment the corresponding counter, probably using a chained conditional.
2. You could create a list with 26 elements. Then you could convert each character to a number (using the built-in function ord), use the number as an index into the list, and increment the appropriate counter.

for the 2nd part I don't understand what using the ord function has to do with indexing to the list. since ord return the unicode of the character not an index. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: It's suggesting that you convert a character to an integer using `ord`, and then use the integer as the index of a list.

Comment: Hint: `ord(current character)-ord('a')` will give you the index for your list. Assuming the string is in lower case.

Comment: oh I got it (after thinking for an hour).... thank you so much for the response and that hint really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ord()` function will return the ascii value of a character.

The 2nd point says that you create a list of length 26 (as english letters are 26) and each entry will have the frequency of that letter.

> Eg: 'a' = 0; 'b' = 1;... 'z': 25

`ord('a')` gives 97 - *ASCII value of 'a'.*

Create a list of size 26 with all `0`'s

> lst = [0] * 26

Now, the entry

> `lst[0]` contains the frequency of character `'a'`

> `lst[1]` contains the frequency of character `'b'`

> `lst[25]` contains the frequency of character `'z'`

Now the character `a` should map to `lst[0]`. To do that we do the following

> `ord('a') - ord('a')` gives you 97-97 = 0. This is the index where `a`'s frequency get stored - `lst[0]`

Similarly you offset the remaining characters by doing `ord(character) - ord('a')`.

> `ord('b') - ord('a')` = 98-97 = 1; `lst[1]`

> `ord('c') - ord('a')` = 99-97 = 2; `lst[2]`

> `ord('z') - ord('a')` = 122 - 97 = 25; `lst[25]`